# Can convertible cooling AC from Carrier lower its capacity for small room?

Tags: air-conditioning

I am planning to install a split 1.5 ton convertible inverter ac from Carrier in a room of size ~100 sq ft. It's unnecessary I know but we would eventually move into a bigger house with bigger rooms ~170 sq ft.

Can I lower the power consumption to say 50% since the current room is small, thus consuming power just like a 0.8 ton aircon would?

Comment: Is your question about the tonnage or the power use?

Comment: I'm curious about how you would "lower the power consumption".

Comment: @FreeMan  I think his reasoning is that since it's a larger than needed unit, it won't take as long to cool the smaller room. The problem with this logic is that while the unit runs for less time, it take more energy to run it .

Comment: Fair point, @JACK. Unfortunately, it won't impact the rate at which the room regains heat, so it will actually kick on _more_ frequently. Made up numbers: 1-ton AC cools room in 10 minutes; 1.5 ton cools in 7 minutes; it takes 30 minutes to warm back up enough to cause AC to kick in. 1-ton unit runs 10 minutes out of 40 minutes (25% of time), 1.5-ton unit runs 7 minutes out of 37 (19%) of time.  Huh... assuming these numbers, maybe it would use less power. As noted, the 1.5 ton will take more power per minute. Would have to factor that in, too.

Comment: @FreeMan i was referring to its 4-in1 convertible cooling. wouldn't it consume less power if it runs at 75%?

Comment: As you may have figured by my questions, I'm no HVAC expert. Please [edit] your question to include the specifics (brand/model) of the units you're considering (links to their spec sheets would be most helpful, too), and I'm sure that someone will be able to help you out.

Comment: When it runs at 75%, is it somehow running the compressor cycle less, or is it simply a slower fan?

Comment: With inverters it takes less power to run at a lower level but an oversized unit will still stop more often and that’s where the big cost is. I understand wanting to take your unit with you but do you realize the cost of set up, pump down then to move another set up & pump down you may be paying almost as much to move the now used unit as a smaller one would cost. I would look into a smaller unit and plan to leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did find out that the convertible AC from carrier has multiple modes, which scales the compressor accordingly. The tonnage can be switched between 0.8, 1.2, 1.5 tonnes.
https://rukminim2.flixcart.com/image/832/832/klfhk7k0/air-conditioner-new/k/b/w/24k-5-star-ester-nxi-hybridjet-inverter-r32-split-ac-split-original-imagyk2qwyshnhuy.jpeg